# Windows Network List Manager domain auth profile

Tags: networking, windows-server, nla

My win 10 clients detect just fine that they are in a domain network and hence set the network connection profile to domain auth.
My Win 11 test machines (both on a physical machine and on a VM) do not detect the correct profile but detect a "public" profile.
I do not find any current information what changed in win 11. The old info does not help [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317051942/http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2010/09/08/network-location-awareness-nla-and-how-it-relates-to-windows-firewall-profiles.aspx)

Test-ComputerSecureChannel returns true and GPOs are processed fine so the general connection to the DCs seems to work

Any idea what i can do to get the NlaSvc to detect a domain auth profile?